# SQL Server : query for DENSE_RANK() grouped by 2 column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help in construct SQL, over an orders table, that holds the Date, SalesID, ItemID and other misc. columns.
Table looks like:

```
Date                   SalesID      ItemID
13-9-15 6:15:00         56            6
13-9-15 6:00:00         56            6
13-9-15 6:26:00         56            4
13-9-15 6:38:00         34            4
13-9-15 7:05:00         34            2
13-9-15 6:42:00         12            2
13-9-15 7:20:00         12            5
13-9-15 7:34:00         78            5
13-9-15 7:41:00         78            6
```

What I'd like to have as an additional column is, one counter which is increments each time when new SalesID begins order by date.And the counter column will count until max no is 3.I'm using DENSE_RANK()for the increment column.

Finally what I need:

```
Date                  SalesID       ItemID     Counter
13-9-15 6:00:00          56           6          1
13-9-15 6:15:00          56           6          1
13-9-15 6:26:00          56           4          1
13-9-15 6:38:00          34           4          2
13-9-15 6:42:00          34           2          2
13-9-15 7:05:00          12           2          3
13-9-15 7:20:00          12           5          3
13-9-15 7:34:00          78           5          1
13-9-15 7:41:00          78           6          1
```

Comment: is this mysql or sqlserver ? Which version of RDMS are you using ?

Comment: Posted addition to my solution that also works for sqlserver 2008

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for sqlserver 2012+. I had to correct invalid data in your example in order to get the correct output

```
DECLARE @t table(Date datetime, SalesID int, ItemID int)
INSERT @t values
('2015-09-13 6:15:00',56,6),
('2015-09-13 6:00:00',56,6),
('2015-09-13 6:26:00',56,4),
('2015-09-13 6:38:00',34,4),
('2015-09-13 6:42:00',34,2),
('2015-09-13 7:05:00',12,2),
('2015-09-13 7:10:00',12,5),
('2015-09-13 7:34:00',78,5),
('2015-09-13 7:41:00',78,6)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    [Date], [SalesID], [ItemID],
    CASE WHEN lag(SalesID) over (order by Date) = SalesID 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END x
  FROM @t
)
SELECT 
  [Date], [SalesID], [ItemID],
  (sum(x) over (ORDER BY Date) - 1) % 3 + 1  [Counter]
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
Date              SalesID  ItemID   Counter
2015-09-13 06:00  56       6        1
2015-09-13 06:15  56       6        1
2015-09-13 06:26  56       4        1
2015-09-13 06:38  34       4        2
2015-09-13 06:42  34       2        2
2015-09-13 07:05  12       2        3
2015-09-13 07:10  12       5        3
2015-09-13 07:34  78       5        1
2015-09-13 07:41  78       6        1
```

This will work for sqlserver 2008:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT
  [Date], 
  SalesID,
  ItemID,
  row_number() over (order by Date)-
    row_number() over (partition by SalesID order by Date) x
 FROM @t
)
SELECT 
  [Date], 
  SalesID,
  ItemID,
  (dense_rank() over (order by x) - 1) % 3 + 1 [Counter]
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Ohh noo...I'm using SqlServer 2008..its have other way to get what exactly I need.